# Proving Tonelli's Theorem for $n$ Factors

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Am trying to prove the following extension of Tonelli's theorem:

**Proposition.** Let $(\Omega_j,\mathcal{A}_j,\mu_j)$ $j=1,\dots,n$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Let $f\to[0,\infty]$ be an $\mathcal{A}_1\otimes \dots\otimes\mathcal{A}_n$ measurable function on $\Omega_1\times\dots\times\Omega_n$. Then for every permutation $j_1,\dots,j_n$ of $1,\dots,n$ we have

$$\int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n) \,d (\mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n)=\int \dots \int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n)\,d\mu_{j_1}\dots d\mu_{j_n}$$

where each integral on th RHS is measurable with respect to the product of the $\mathcal{A}_j$ corresponding to coordinates in which integration has not yet occured. My book says it's a simple induction but somehow my proof seems complicated.

I believe it is sufficient to consider the case of the identity permutation. This is because we have the equality

$$\int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n) \,d (\mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n)=\int f(\omega_{1},\dots,\omega_{n}) \,d (\mu_{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_{j_n})$$

see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799818/does-order-matter-when-integrating-with-product-measures). In other words, it does not matter whether we regard $f$ as a function on $\Omega_1\times\dots\times\Omega_n$ or on $\Omega_{j_1}\times\dots\times\Omega_{j_n}$.

Is this correct? The comments seem to indicate that are multiple possible approaches here. Any proof outline is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Standard usage is $\displaystyle \int \cdots g\,dx\,dy$ rather than $\displaystyle \int \cdots g dxdy,$ i.e. some space separates $dx$ and $dy$ from neighboring expressions. I edited accordingly. I also chance $\displaystyle\int\int$ to $\displaystyle \iint,$ coded as `\iint`. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you. And for the question?

Comment: It is enough to poof the statement for $(\Omega_1\times\prod^n_{j=2}\Omega_j,\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\bigotimes^n_{j=2}\mathcal{A}_j,\mu_1\otimes(\bigotimes^n_{j=2}\mu_j))$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz What do you mean?

Comment: @Alphie: I mean that the whole statement in the problem is a consequence of the result for a product of two spaces and a simple induction argument.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes if we keep the the original order of coordinates. But do you agree with the part where I say that we can assume the identity permutation?

Comment: @Alphie: he ordering is a not a problem. It is trivially true for to factors and the rest is by induction.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Am having trouble with the ordering part. Could you provide the details of the induction step?

Comment: I would frame the argument differently. The group of permutation of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ is generated by inversions of two consecutive indices : $(i, i+1)$ in cycle notation. Proof: the bubble sort algortihm ends. Thus you only need to prove the proposition for these inversions, where it is a direct consequence of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem for $2$ spaces.

Comment: @D.Thomine I understand the generating part, but I don't see how you can inverse say the 3rd and 4th middle coordinates. Is it still an induction argument? But do you agree that by symmetry integrating with $\mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n$ is the same as integrating with $ \mu_{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_{j_n}$?

Comment: @D.Thomine If we forget about the permutation part, then induction gives us that $\int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_{n}) \,d (\mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n)=\int \dots \int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_{n})\,d\mu_1\dots d\mu_{n}$ and so if I understand correctly you suggest showing that we can interchange the order of adjacent coordinates on the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write down a statement of Tonelli's theorem, just to make everything clear.

Let $(X, \mathcal M, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal N, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f: X \times Y \to [0,\infty]$ be $\mathcal M \otimes \mathcal N$ measurable. Then:
$$\int f d(\mu \times \nu) = \int \left(\int f(x_1, x_2) d\nu(x_2)\right) d\mu(x_1) = \int \left(\int f(x_1, x_2) d\mu(x_1)\right) d\nu(x_2).$$

Alright now we can write down a proof of your statement. Let $(X_j, \mathcal M_j, \mu_j)$ be a finite collection of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and let $f : \prod_{j=1}^n X_j \to [0,\infty]$ be $\bigotimes_{j=1}^n \mathcal M_j$ measureable.

Note that $\bigotimes_{j=1}^n \mathcal{M}_j = \mathcal M_1 \otimes \bigotimes_{j=2}^n \mathcal M_j$, that $\mu_1 \times \mu_2 \times \cdots \times \mu_n = \mu_1 \times (\mu_2 \times \cdots \times \mu_n)$, and that $(\prod_{j=2}^n X_j,  \bigotimes_{j=2}^n \mathcal M_j, \mu_2 \times \cdots \mu_n)$ is $\sigma$-finite (this is direct from proving the product of $\sigma$-finite measure spaces is $\sigma$-finite and induction).

Thus repeated application of the first application of Tonelli's theorem above (i.e. an induction) gives that:
$$\int f d(\mu_1 \times \cdots \times \mu_n) = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_1(x_1)\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_n(x_n).$$

Now we show inductively show that, under the assumptions of our proposition, that:
$$\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_1(x_1)\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_n(x_n) = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_{\sigma(1)}(x_{\sigma(1)})\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_{\sigma(n)}(x_{\sigma(n)})$$
for any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$.

It is clearly true for $n=1$.

Suppose it has been shown for $n$, then choose $\sigma \in S_{n+1}$. Then define $\tau \in S_n$ inductively by $\tau(1) = \sigma(1)$ if $\sigma(1) \ne n+1$ else $\sigma(2)$ and $\tau(j+1) = \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(\tau(j))+1)$ if $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(\tau(j))+1) \ne n+1$ else $= \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(\tau(j))+2)$.

The result is that $\tau$ arranges $1,...,n$ in the same order as $\sigma$. Then applying the inductive hypothesis with $\tau$ to the interior integral for each $x_{n+1}$:
$$\int \left (\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_1(x_1)\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_n(x_n) \right) d\mu_{n+1}(x_{n+1}) = \int \left(\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_{\tau(1)}(x_{\tau(1)})\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_{\tau(n)}(x_{\tau(n)})\right) d\mu_{n+1}(x_{n+1}).$$
Then since $\tau$ put $1,...,n$ into the same order as $\sigma$, all that is left to get $1,...,n+1$ into the order induced by $\sigma$ is to insert $d\mu_{n+1}(x_{n+1})$ in the right spot, for which it suffices to show that two adjacent $d\mu_i(x_i)$ and $d\mu_j(x_j)$ can be commuted (then repeatedly commuting $d\mu_{n+1}(x_{n+1})$ left until it is in the right spot finishes the proof).

This we will now do. Claim:
$$\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_i  \bigg) d\mu_j \cdots \right) d\mu_b(x_n) = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_j  \bigg) d\mu_i \cdots \right) d\mu_b(x_n).$$

But this is just a direct application of Tonelli's theorem, since it suffices to show that:
$$\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_i  \right) d\mu_j  = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_j  \right) d\mu_i,$$
and we have:
$$\int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_i  \right) d\mu_j  = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \right) d\mu_j \times \mu_i = \int \left(\cdots \left(\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d\mu_a(x_1)\right) \cdots \bigg) d\mu_j  \right) d\mu_i.$$

Putting it together completes the proof.

Note: Alternatively, instead of all that $\tau$ stuff, we can use the final claim to show that the set of permutations of the measures is a subgroup containing consecutive permutations: $(i, i+1)$ and then prove that $(i, i+1)$ generates $S_n$, which effectively what I did in the "$\tau$-section", though it might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed proof. Indeed there is a bit of work besides just the simple induction. But do you agree with my comment that $\int f(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n) \,d (\mu_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_n)=\int f(\omega_{1},\dots,\omega_{n}) \,d (\mu_{j_1} \otimes \dots \otimes \mu_{j_n})$ and so we could assume no permutation at all?

Comment: No. It seems in the linked post, you got into more details that may give meaning to that statement, but on the face of it, it doesn't make sense, as $\mu_{j_1} \times \cdots \times \mu_{j_n}$ is a measure on the measurable space attached to $X_{j_1} \times \cdots \times X_{j_n}$ while $f$ has domain $X_1 \times \cdots X_n$, so the domain of the function doesn't line up with the "domain" of the measure. On the other hand, if you reinterpret $f$ as a function on $X_{j_1} \times \cdots \times X_{j_n}$ in the natural way, it should be true, but then you get a statement like:

Comment: $\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d (\mu_1 \times \cdots \times d\mu_n) = \int f \circ \sigma(x_{j_1},\cdots, x_{j_n}) d (\mu_{j_1} \times \cdots \times d\mu_{j_n})$. Then the easy induction gives that $ \int f(x_1,...,x_n) d (\mu_1 \times \cdots \times d\mu_n) = \int \cdots \int f \circ \sigma (x_{j_1}, \cdots, x_{j_n}) d\mu_{j_1} \cdots d\mu_{j_n}$ and there's still some work in showing this is equal to the right thing.

Comment: The point is it might work, but there's definitely some annoying work to be done either way.

Comment: @Alphie Also if the proof makes sense, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes I met looking at $f$ now as a function $X_{j_1} \times \cdots \times X_{j_n}$ in the natural way.

Comment: The equality $\int f(x_1,...,x_n) d (\mu_1 \times \cdots \times d\mu_n) = \int \cdots \int f \circ \sigma (x_{j_1}, \cdots, x_{j_n}) d\mu_{j_1} \cdots d\mu_{j_n}$ seems immediate to me since in each step we integrate with respect to one variable only, and the restrictions of $f$ and $ f \circ \sigma (x_{j_1}, \cdots, x_{j_n})$ to a single variable are indeed the same (as functions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112487/discussion-between-keefer-rowan-and-alphie).